What kind of solar panels did Landsat 5 use?
I would like to know everything possible about the solar panels Landsat 4/5 used. But for now, let's start with *what kind of solar panels they were.
Those things survived ~150,000 thermal cycles, and I'd like to know exactly what they were made of. With Googling, I can't even find if they were Si or GaAs.

Everything possible it a bit broad could you be more specific

@Starship I've made an edit to narrow this one down; sometimes users forget they can ask as many (good) questions as they like.

This document on NTRS may have more information, but a document request is required to get access to it.

You are right, many sources on google do not provide complete or any information on the solar arrays.
Through this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_4#:~:text=The%20satellite%20was%20constructed%20with,produced%201430%20W%20of%20power. (scroll to Satellite Designs) , I was able to gather that the Landsat 4 used a single solar array that had one axis of articulation, and that the solar array produced 1430W of power it charged three NiCd batteries. Any other info such as the type and model of the array I was unable to find.

@Ludo The document is here https://archive.org/details/nasa-reports_nas-1552326-vol1/page/n27/mode/2up It was one of the MMS spacecraft designed to be Shuttle repairable.

@OrganicMarble thanks! Unfortunately, no new information...
